# curl request hangs waiting for response

Tags: unix, curl, networking

I have developed a Svelte app. I run it like so:

```
nohup ./run.sh &
```

where `run.sh` is defined as:

```
#!/bin/bash
npm run dev -- --host 0.0.0.0 > output.log 2>&1
```

It starts the server and I can see:

```
> svelte-app@0.0.1 dev
> vite dev --host 0.0.0.0



  VITE v4.4.8  ready in 1033 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://x.x.x.x:5173/
  ➜  press h to show help
```

in `output.log`. Further I can see:

```
$ ss -tpln
State      Recv-Q     Send-Q         Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port     Process
LISTEN     23         511                  0.0.0.0:5173               0.0.0.0:*         users:(("node",pid=2589,fd=25))
```

but when I make a `curl` request to the app, the request hangs:

```
$ curl -vvv localhost:5173
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:5173...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5173 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5173
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
>
```

After much debugging, I found that if I make one simple change which is to do:

```
./run.sh
```

instead of:

```
nohup ./run.sh &
```

the problem vanishes. can someone explain this to me?